# How to get selected row index on @change event of child Select Dropdown in Element UI?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I'm generating a list of multiple input elements in which one is `<el-select>`. On changing this select menu, I'm getting value bounded with that select. But here, question is, I also want to get index/row number of the parent v-for items.
You can understand what I meant from the following code:

```
<el-form-item v-for="(domain, index) in Prescription.domains">
    <div class="col-md-2" v-if="medicineIsSelected === true">
        <small>Select Brand:</small>
        <el-select v-model="domain.SelectedBrand" clearable placeholder="Select" @change="updateDropdowns"> <!-- Here I want to pass {{index}} also -->
          <el-option
            v-for="item in selectedMedicineMetaInfo.BrandName"
            :key="item.value.name"
            :label="item.value.name"
            :value="item.value.rxcui">
          </el-option>
        </el-select>
    </div>
</el-form-item>
```

As you can see from above code, I want to pass index in `updateDropdowns`.
I tried passing updateDropdowns(index), here I got the index number but lost the selected value of that dropdown. How can I pass both?

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution :

```
@change="updateDropdowns(index, $event)"
```

you can use $event to reference current event.

Comment: Wow! you are a lifesaver! Thanks a lot! Works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

you can use custom event to manage this

```
<div>
   <child @clicked="ongetChild"></child>
</div>
```

== child ==

watch your dropdown changes

```
export default {
 watch: {
 'domain.SelectedBrand':function(value) {
   this.$emit('clicked', 'value')
 }
}}
```

=== parent ==

```
export default {
 ongetChild (value) {
  console.log(value) // someValue
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using any parent-child components. How can I do with ElementUI?

Comment: easily you can create child component for el-select

Answer (score 1):

Use  `@change="updateDropdowns"` in `el-select` tag

Use vue method:

```
updateDropdowns(index) {
    this.selectedMedicineMetaInfo.BrandName[index-1]; // this gives selected option details
}
```